# ngTagsInput issue with ng-invalid style

Tags: ng-tags-input

I'm using https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput.
I created a basic form with a url and a tag-input field that is required.
Since it's required, i used the attribute min-tags="1"

I used it in conjonction with bootstrap stylehseet.

When displayed, the field appears with a red shadow border (since it is empty), even before any submit of the form. This is really annoying, is there any workaround ?

1. Validate the field only after form submission ?
2. Removing min-tags="1" and find another way to check the required aspect.
3. Playing with css to discard those styles applied to this .ng-invalid .tags

Thank you

Edit :
sample code :

```
<tags-input min-tags="1" ng-model="mytags"></tags-input>
```

Have done a plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/EQcYfr4vLpkeJESho3GL?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a custom class to handle the pristine state:

**CSS**

```
.custom-tags.ng-pristine .tags {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tags-input min-tags="1" ng-model="mytags" class="custom-tags"></tags-input>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vXUenuD7QVmGmAXa1bI4?p=preview)

Also, Angular 1.3 isn't officially supported yet. This is particularly important here because both pristine and dirty states won't be correctly set if you use that version of the framework.

Comment: nice, almost done, i just add this in a ng-class to get red border when field is submitted empty : `ng-class="{'custom-tags': !forms.createVideoForm.$submitted}"` and works perfect, thanks